# Adding multiple inputs and incrementing their names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found many answers on adding text inputs dynamically, but I can't seem to find a source on naming the inputs. For example if I have 3 inputs on one line and the user adds another row I would need the output as:

> name_1 text_1 subject_1
>
> name_2 text_2 subject_2

Below is what I have so far and here is a link to my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKdVYx)

```
    <table id="speedTable">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <a href="" id="add-button">
        <img width="16" height="16" title="Click here to add a time entry." alt="Click here to add a time entry." src="/images/add.png">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label style="position:relative;" for="start_run_length">Start Run Length</label>
        <input style="" type="text" id="start_run_length" name="start_run_length_0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label style="position:relative;" for="end_run_length">End Run Length</label>
        <input style="" type="text" id="end_run_length" name="end_run_length_0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label style="position:relative;" for="impressions_per_hr">Speed-Impressions/hr</label>
        <input style="" type="text" id="impressions_per_hr" name="impressions_per_hr_0">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
      var scntDiv = $('#speedTable');
      var i = $('#speedTable tbody').size() + 1;

      $('#add-button').on('click', function() {
        $('<tr><td><label style="position:relative;" for="start_run_length">Start Run Length</label><input style="" type="text" id="start_run_length1" name="start_run_length' + i + '"/></td><td><label style="position:relative;" for="end_run_length">End Run Length</label><input style="" type="text" id="end_run_length" name="end_run_length' + i + '"></td><td><label style="position:relative;" for="impressions_per_hr">Speed-Impressions/hr</label><input style="" type="text" id="impressions_per_hr" name="impressions_per_hr' + i + '"></td></tr>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
      });

    });
```

EDIT for solution and reference:

```
$(function() {

var idx = 0;
var scntDiv = $('#speedTable');
var htmlContent1a = '<tr><td><label style="position:relative;">Start Run Length</label><input style="" type="text" class="selector" id="start_run_length';
var htmlContent1b = '" name="start_run_length';

var htmlContent2a = '"></td><td><label style="position:relative;">End Run Length</label><input style="" type="text" class="selector" id="end_run_length';
var htmlContent2b = '" name="end_run_length';

var htmlContent3a = '"></td><td><label style="position:relative;">Speed-Impressions/hr</label><input style="" type="text" class="selector" id="impressions_per_hr';
var htmlContent3b = '" name="impressions_per_hr';
var htmlContent3c = '"></td></tr>';

          $('#add-button').on('click', function() {
            //increment an index
            idx++;
            var newContent = htmlContent1a + idx + htmlContent1b + idx + htmlContent2a + idx + htmlContent2b + idx + htmlContent3a + idx + htmlContent3b + idx + htmlContent3c;
              $(newContent).appendTo("#tableBody");
          });
        });
```

Comment: Use an array to add the numbers. When a box is added; increment the number.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea by appending the iterator interger to the name, you need to do the same with the id attributes.

A better way to do this though is to use an array as the name.

```
name='whatever[]'
```

..that way you don't have to worry about appending the number.

But that creates the problem of not being able to associate each inputs with the other ones on the same row. I often add a `data-index` attribute to help with that.

on each input that you're creating dynamically add a `data-index="'+i+'"` parameter, then you can get the entire row using one jquery selector.

```
var row = $("input[data-index='1']"); // returns all rows in the 2nd column
startInput = row[0];
endInput = row[1];
theOtherInput = row[2];
```

Comment: Fairly new to Jquery, I get what you mean but do you have an example? Every time I have tried that it throws me an error.

Comment: "Oh, thanks for answering my question, I'm not gonna give you an upvote or anything, but will you write my code for me anyway..." no, i'm not gonna do that.

Comment: I was able to find an example and figured it out. Sorry didn't want you to write it, just a sample. I am too new to be able to give an up vote.

Comment: well im glad you figured it out. for future reference you don't wanna ask people for code on SO, it never goes over well. godspeed.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull, you cannot have the the same id for several tags. I changed ids to classes.

```
 $(function() {
          var scntDiv = $('#speedTable');

          $('#add-button').on('click', function() {
            var i = $('#speedTable tbody').size() + 1;
            $('<tr><td><label style="position:relative;" for="start_run_length">Start Run Length</label><input style="" type="text" class="start_run_length" name="start_run_length' + i + '"/></td><td><label style="position:relative;" for="end_run_length">End Run Length</label><input style="" type="text" class="end_run_length" name="end_run_length' + i + '"></td><td><label style="position:relative;" for="impressions_per_hr">Speed-Impressions/hr</label><input style="" type="text" class="impressions_per_hr" name="impressions_per_hr' + i + '"></td></tr>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            return false;
          });

        });
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that.